# Questions about pre-rendering in Nuxt 3

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, middleware, nuxtjs3, prerender

Context:

We are finding setting up Nuxt 3 in SSG mode quite confusing particular when running in dev mode locally. We are moving from a Vite vue 3 project where we were using vite-ssg to pre-render. We just ran the project in dev mode to work normally then we would kill the running instance and do a build which would do the pre-rendering. We would then put that build on an S3 bucket.
We are just trying to replicate the same state in Nuxt 3 until we have more experience with running a node server on Netlify, Ec2 instance or something else.

Questions:

1. We only want to run the project by building it and hosting it on an S3 bucket, some routes will be pre-rendered and others will not but we only want to do the pre-rendering at build. Does the below config look correct?

```js
    // https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
    export default defineNuxtConfig({
       ssr: true,
       // Is this considered hybrid rendering? Are we allowed to do this if we only want to use SSG mode? 
       routeRules: {
          // Logged out pages pre-rendered at build time
          "/": { prerender: true },
           "/terms": { prerender: true },
          "/privacy": { prerender: true },
          "/account": { ssr: false },
          "/home": { ssr: false },
       },
       ...
```

2. Should we always do this in the middleware to stop the server interfering with route gaurds? I dont see what the use of the server in middleware actually is?

```js
    if (process.server) {
         return;
    }
```

The reason why I ask this is because of authentication. We need to do the following:

```js
    if(!auth.loggedIn()) redirect "/login".
```

However, the server always sees auth.loggedIn() as false (even though the client is true) and therefor it redirects to login. Im very confused as to why when im running in dev mode, the server is doing this. Shouldnt the Client always take priority here?

3- Why does a server run by default in Dev if we only want to build the project and deploy?